# Can I lock my computer and have my monitors turn off immediately? (Arch with xfce)

Tags: arch-linux, xfce, monitors

My monitors turn off at the interval I have them set at (12 minutes, which is 2 minutes after my blank screen saver is activated). But, if I use my lock combo which I've bound to super-L, they stay on indefinitely it seems (basically, overnight when I go to sleep). I know this, because the little lights don't blink like they do when they're "offline".

I've only encountered this since I installed Arch (about 2 weeks ago). I previously had Manjaro installed, as well as Xubuntu and ArchLabs. I'm thinking the other distros had a package that didn't come with Arch which may address this? They were set up similarly and after the set time, would turn off, but would also turn off if I locked the computer.

Comment: It looks like your "screen saver" and "screen locker" may actually be two separate bits of software, with different functionalities and/or configurations. So, what exactly have you configured to happen when you press Super-L? Does it run some command, and if so, which one? And are you running a screen saver/locker application like `xfce4-screensaver` or `xscreensaver`, or just relying on the X server's default screensaver/powersaver functionality? Without this kind of information it will be really hard to guess what is going on with your system.

Comment: I would probably go to the keyboard settings, edit the lock shortcut, and paste this following code `xset dpms force off && xflock4`

Comment: @telcoM I have super-L bound to `xflock4`. @S.Goswami I will try that, thank you. Edit: Now super-L doesn't do anything.

Comment: You need to add this to be specific: `bash -c "xset dpms force off && xflock4"`, xfce4 keyboard shortcuts doesn't work with long scripts... But the problem is it will initially set the display to off and turn execute xflock4, but once you move your mouse or press a key, the display will turn on. If you have xscreensaver or other screensavers, it won't be able to turn your display off again...

Comment: @S.Goswami Thank you, that worked! I'd vote this as solved if you wish to put it as an answer.

Comment: Thanks, but it's a temporary solution, seems like using `xset dpms force off` changes the audio connection from HDMI to Analog on my laptop connected to a monitor. Also, it can cause trouble when xscreensaver is active, which will not let the screen go black again once it's wake! If you have xscreensaver, changing the `dpmsEnabled` to `True`, `dpmsOff` to `0:00:00` and `mode` to blank has the similar effect...

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. I also appreciate your extended explanation. (Edit: I don't have enough rep to upvote your comments, which I just realised. :()